# How to implement pagination with display tag and get records from database for each page

Tags: postgresql, jsp, spring-mvc, pagination, displaytag

I am new to spring mvc and there is requirement to display records in a jsp using pagination.Database contains more than 100k rows and I cant fetch all the rows in single query and cache it. I have seen some examples with getting records in single query and doing cache but in my case when user clicks on each page link i want query the database and fetch the records every time.I googled it.Many mentioned about PaginatedList Interface of display tag.But i have no idea how to implement it

How to work with display tag using PaginatedList Interface or are there any alternate

I am using spring mvc4.1 ,postgressql 9.4 and jdbc template and jsp

Comment: Can you use Spring Data JPA which has Pagination built in?

Comment: I already started using DAO with jdbc template layer now project is in live. At this point of time i dont want to move to JPA so that i want to use display tag